# TFS Conflict Type: Writable File - A writable file by same name exists locally

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

I'm trying to get latest of my project. When I do, TFS shows me that I have conflicts on every single file in that project.  Every file has the same conflict: `Conflict Type: Writable File - A writable file by same name exists locally.`

The resolution it gives me is "Overwrite Local File or Folder" but I have to do this one by one.

Why does TFS thinks that I have conflicts (I haven't changed any files)?

Comment: I have recently come across this problem. I'm wondering if this is because I was working within to separate instances of VS at the same time, however only pulled the latest version from one environment. The other VS is for a different database altogether hence working within two different versions As a result, I wonder if this is the reason why the error happened in the first place this time around, rather than the post by Edward Thomson above?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Grant's answer is great for how to resolve multiple conflicts.

As for why you *have* those conflicts, generally speaking, your TFS client has detected that a file exists locally that is not managed by TFS, but you are trying to perform a get operation that would overwrite that file.

If you're following a normal development workflow (and not going and editing files outside of your editor), the most common source of writable conflicts is from shelvesets.  If you were to pend an add on a file, then you were to undo that add (either explicitly or because you shelved the change and deselected the preserve pending changes button), the file is **not** deleted.  (This is to prevent data loss - it's not uncommon that you would want to create a file but *not* have it checked in to source control.)

Now if you (or someone else) were to check in that shelveset (either through creating a build from that shelveset, or from gated check-in, or because your code reviewer checked in your shelveset directly), then when you do a get latest, your TFS client will detect that the file still exists locally and thus, you'll have a writable conflict.

This may not be particularly obvious in the case of gated check-in.  How gated check-in actually works is when you try to check in your changes, *your check-in is actually converted to a shelveset*.  The TFS build agent will then try to build your shelveset, and if the build succeeds, it will then check-in that shelveset on your behalf.  If the build fails, the shelveset remains and you can unshelve to fix the build errors.

For this reason, it's important to run the build notification application when you're using gated check-in, which will allow you to "reconcile" your changes once they're submitted.  Reconciling your check-in will simply do a get of the check-in that was submitted by the build server, but it will avoid conflicts since it understands the context of the changes that are on your local disk.  (It will compare the contents on your local disk to the contents on the server.)  If you do not choose to reconcile, you will, unfortunately, have writable conflicts on files that were added.

(Note that this scenario [will not produce a conflict in the next version of TFS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/08/31/merge-enhancements-in-tfs-11.aspx) - if there are no content differences, TFS will not produce a conflict.)

Comment: I checked-in the changes, TFS should know that these files are under source control.  Couple of days ago I created and checked in all the changes for the project. Other people on the team were able to get my changes(which means they weren't shelved right?) the changes were actually checked successfully.  If so, tfs should know that these files are under source control...right?

Comment: @dev.e.loper Are you using gated check-in?

Comment: Yes. My first time using a gated check-in. Why?

Comment: Gated check-in uses shelvesets to perform its magic.  I'll update the answer to flesh out the details a little bit.

Comment: I didn't know that gated check-in creates a shelve set. When the gated check-in build succeeded, it prompted me with a window. I think it said 'would you like to reconcile some changes' and I didn't know what it was and in a hurry I clicked Ignore.

Comment: Also, I haven't had a chance to confirm this but it might be a permissions issue while Reconciling. http://www.benday.com/2010/09/09/tfs2010-reconcile-workspace-after-gated-checkin-is-weird-if-visual-studio-2010-is-elevated/

Answer (score 32):

The Visual Studio 2010 conflict resolution dialog supports multi-select.

If you select the first conflict, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> then select the last conflict, the "Overwrite Local File or Folder" resolution will be applied to all the selected conflicts.

You can also use the command-line tool [tf resolve /auto:OverwriteLocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yw3tcdy.aspx) to resolve the conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm trying to use tf command line utility and running into issues. I created a different question with details over here http://stackoverflow.com/q/9264553/37759

Comment: Ctrl-A (select all) also appears to work in VS2012 and is a bit faster

Comment: So obvious! You saved my day! :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do it for whole folder, multiple folders or entire project where conflict files exist.

[image]

You need to right click on that specific file/folder, go to Advanced, Select "Get Specific Version..."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must have all Rights (Full control) to a specific local file or folder. Check it out. If it's not true you have to delete all local files, change Rights and then get latest files from server.