# Remove TFS Local File Conflicts with CommandLine

Tags: command-line, version-control, tfs

I trying to update my local copy with TFS server project. Currently there is no workspace mapping (I have deleted the previous mapping) in my current copy.  Now i have create a new workspace and mapped it with the same Local copy.

Now, whenever i am trying to run the TFS get command it says some local file is writable, therefore the checkout is getting failed.

**ERROR:**

```
/project/Test/css/v2/scss/utilities.scss: Local file     /protextsoftwarescan1/project/Test/css/v2/scss/utilities.scss is writable
/project/Test/css/v2/utilities.css: Local file /protextsoftwarescan1/project/Test/css/v2/utilities.css is writable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run [tf resolve /auto:OverwriteLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yw3tcdy.aspx) command to resolve the conflicts.

The **OverwriteLocal** option overwrites the file in your workspace with the server version. This is used to resolve conflicts that arise from a writable file in your workspace.

Please check Edward's and Grant's answer in this link for the details: [TFS Conflict Type: Writable File - A writable file by same name exists locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262005/tfs-conflict-type-writable-file-a-writable-file-by-same-name-exists-locally)