# Visual Studio 2015 - Merge tool button missing

Tags: tfs, merge, visual-studio-2015

I'm having problems with merge tool in Visual Studio 2015. I didn't need the merge tool for the longest time, I haven't used it for couple of months. Now when I need it I can't find it. I was trying to google and find an answer, checking VS settings but with no success. I can only see buttons 'Overwrite Local File or Folder' and 'Keep Local File Contents'. When I press Compare button, I see diff tool but I'm not able to accept changes (check buttons are missing).

What am I doing wrong? How can I merge two files?
 [image: Screenshot of my Visual Studio with Resolve Conflicts screen]

Answer (score 0):

Please navigate to files in source control

```
Right click on file/folder you want to branch>>Merge
```

[Full list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181428.aspx) of other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is because these files in your local folder are not been tracked by TFS Version Control. For example, you added a file "readme.txt" in you local folder and hadn't check-in them into version control. Another people in your team also added this file in the same relative path and checked it into version control. Now, when you get the latest version or check in your changes, you will get the behavior as your screenshot. A similar question can be found here: [TFS Conflict Type: Writable File - A writable file by same name exists locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262005/tfs-conflict-type-writable-file-a-writable-file-by-same-name-exists-locally)

Answer (score 0):

It's doing exactly the same things in Visual Studio 2017.

If you had a problem in workspace and you rollback it from a save, you can have the same issue.

You need to rebind some of the project by yourself first like the asked question here : [Re etablish TFS source control bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128730/re-establish-tfs-source-control-bindings), then if all is going well you will see the button.

If it's not working, try to use external merge tool which will allow you to edit thoses files.